# Selection of text appears across window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, selection

So I am using a function to select text in a `<div>`. It works, but I don't like the way it displays in Google Chrome. You can see my work [here](http://www.dstrout.net/pub/selectdiv.htm). Click the button and the text in the `<div>` gets selected, but in Chrome, the selection stretches all the way across to the right of the window, which isn't good. It works like I want it in Firefox and IE, though.

The `<div>`, of course, has a width on it of 200px. I tried also putting a `max-width` declaration on, but that wasn't any good either. Is there any way to keep the selection from displaying this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the CSS rule `display:inline-block` to your div:

```
#result {
    width: 200px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}
​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Bjs4x/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selectNodeContents()` instead of `selectNode()`: http://jsfiddle.net/6XUJR/

Comment: This works, but what are the advantages of this over the answer by @j08691 ?

Comment: Your `div` stays a block-level element, if that's an issue you're considering.

Comment: Not really - that's not that important to me.